# conda build fails with `>=` of jinja2 variable in `host` section of recipe

Tags: python, package, dependencies, conda, conda-build

I am using a jinja2 variable in the recipe file of a feedstock, but `conda build` fails to recognize that variable in the `host` part of the `requirements` section when used along with `>=`.

This problem does not happen in the `run` section of recipe.
Also, in the `host` section this problem does not happen if

- I don't use `>=` along with the variable
- I use the hardcoded value along with `>=`

This is the conda recipe which fails with -

$ cat recipe/meta.yaml

```
package:
  name: dummy-conda
  version: 1.1.1

source:
  path: .

requirements:
  host:
    - python >={{python}}
  run:
    - python >={{python}}
```

I have added the variable in another file -

$ cat conda_local_config.yaml

```
python:
  - 3.6
```

And use this command to build

```
$ conda build -m conda_local_config.yaml recipe/
```

which fails with

```
...
Received dictionary as spec.  Note that pip requirements are not supported in conda-build meta.yaml.
```

This is the complete failure log -

```
$ conda build -m conda_local_config.yaml recipe/
No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.11
WARNING:conda_build.metadata:No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.11
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Adding in variants from conda_local_config.yaml
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from conda_local_config.yaml
Received dictionary as spec.  Note that pip requirements are not supported
```

If I modify the recipe file to this

```
..
  host:
    - python {{python}}
..
```

or

```
..
  host:
    - python >=3.6
..
```

the build works fine!

Edit - I opened up a github issue against conda-build to get an official answer to this behavior - https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/3544